# Placing a project on virtual hosting server

Tags: sql, reactjs, build

Good afternoon when placing a project on the dvs hosting server, an error occurs:

root@1983141-cn78041:/home/apps/markssite/frontend# npm i fsevents@latest -f --save-optional npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled. npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY npm ERR! syscall rename npm ERR! path /home/apps/markssite/frontend/node_modules/cssnano-utils npm ERR! dest /home/apps/markssite/frontend/node_modules/.cssnano-utils-jxShfhYw npm ERR! errno -39 npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/home/apps/markssite/frontend/node_modules/cssnano-utils' -> '/home/apps/markssite/frontend/node_modules/.cssnano-utils-jxShfhYw' npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-09-21T14_52_10_208Z-debug-0.log root@1983141-cn78041:/home/apps/markssite/frontend#

What could it be related to?

at startup and npm i this problem occurs

When I try to build it is interrupted and an error pops up

The build failed because the process exited too early. This probably means the system ran out of memory or someone called `kill -9` on the process.

Comment: You have already asked this question one hour ago, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77155192/placing-a-project-on-dvs-server, edit that question instead of asking the same thing one more time.